# Insert into deep embedded document with Mongoose/Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following Schemas in Mongoose/Node.js:

```
var ItemsSchema = new Schema({
    itemname: String,
    quantity: String
});

var ListSchema = new Schema({
    listname: String,
    items: [ItemsSchema]
});

var UsersSchema = new Schema ({    
    username: String,
    owned: [ListSchema]
});
```

So each User may have many Lists. And each list can contain many items. 
How can i insert new item to a specific list?
Using User.findOne({"owned._id" : listid} ... will give me the user that own the specific list but i can't figure it out how to proceed to get the single list.

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to do this.

```
User.findById(id, function(err, doc){
     doc.owned[n].items.push(item);
}
```

Any user has an independent list, you must access to a userlist and push an item to a specific list.

The users don't share the list, of course the items neither with this structure.

Sorry about my english.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! My background is in the relation databases and switching to nosql need some change in perspective :)

Comment: ;) Good luck! Perhaps help you this http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs I use MongoHub for mac, it's great!